# Matching strings that appear in both lower and upper case (or are a combination of lower case and upper case letters)

Tags: stata

I am trying to find a word from a column in Stata that could appear in all caps or all lower case.

```
    foreach varlist_cust in "xyz" "XYZ" "XyZ" {


replace cus_tag = strpos(customer_name, "`varlist_cust'") if cus_tag==0

}
```

Is there a more efficient method of conducting this analysis? Maybe with the use of regular expressions?

Comment: I don't know stata, but did you consider researching how to use regular expressions with it? And how to use regular expression with strpos and  subinstr. Expression like '/xyz/i' would work

Comment: I read a lot about regular expressions and I understand how to use them to find special characters, but I am not sure if I can find an exact word just in different cases using them. I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: For "column" read "variable" (and for "STATA" read "Stata", already corrected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regular expressions as Stata has a built in `lower()` function. See, for example

```
clear
input str9 customer_name
"Ander2Ed"
"sonu"
"abcXyZcba"
"XYZ"
"zXyZ"
end

gen cus_tag = strpos(lower(customer_name), "xyz")
```

Simply evaluate the `customer_name` variable as lowercase against the lowercase values you are looking for.

see `help lower` and `help string functions` for more.