# Summary table of many variables when each needs to be restricted using if

Tags: stata, summary

I have three different variables in Stata, `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`.

I need to make a summary table of these three variables so that I have the observation number, mean, sd, min, max as the fields in the resulting summary table.

I am using the following code :

```
  su var1 if restriction == 2 
  su var2 if restriction == 3 
  su var3 if restriction == 4
```

Since the summary table is created from variables that are applied with restrictions, I am unable to use :

```
  su var1 var2 var3
```

I would be very grateful if anyone has any ideas on how to modify my code so that instead of three lines of code I can use one line of code to get a single table will all the stats I require, which I can then copy as a table into my Word document.

Comment: column (spreadsheet) == variable (Stata). Stata != STATA. The `if` qualifier is **not** the `if` command. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Two of those points were made in replying to your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921539/matching-strings-that-appear-in-both-lower-and-upper-case-or-are-a-combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing reproducible here without example data. Please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

But I would go

```
gen var1_2 = var1 if restriction == 2 
gen var2_3 = var2 if restriction == 3 
gen var3_4 = var3 if restriction == 4 
summarize var1_2 var2_3 var3_4
```